# Run 20 analysis on Sonarqube to do a stress test

Tags: sonarqube, stress-testing

I want to do a stress test of Sonarqube by running 20 analysis at the same time but I didn't found how to do this. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarQube is using a queue to inject analysis into database (with standard configuration) so you won't be able to stress it this way.

Moreover the performance will highly depends on your database performance.